# jQuery - Create new sibling element between two existing elements based on the value of the IDs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a dynamic event calendar list, and I'm trying to figure out a way to add a new element between two elements based on their Ids. The existing elements have a ID that is formatted to be use as the date of the event.

The ID's are created by the date yymmdd

Example

```
<li id="120523">
    This would be an event for May 23rd, 2012
</li>

<li id="120525">
    This would be for May 25th, 2012
</li>
```

What I'm trying to do is to dynamic create a new event and place it in the correct spot. For example: If the user creates another event for May 24th, 2012, it should be placed between the two about li's.

It would have to be dymanic, because if there were ton's of events in the list, only one event per day, it would have to grab the first element that's ID is greater than it, and the first element that's ID is less than it, and create the new element in between them.

Example:

I'm trying to generate something like this:

```
<li id="120504">May 4, 2012<li>
```

and place it in the correct order by id into an unordered-list like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="120123">Jan 23, 2012</li>
<li id="120415">April 15, 2012</li>
<li id="120502">May 2, 2012</li>
// new element should go here
<li id="120520">May 20, 2012</li>
<li id="120816">Aug 16, 2012</li>
</ul>
```

using jQuery

Comment: You should post your HTML for the calendar itself (or at least a snippet of it).  It's hard to decide how to write the jQuery selectors if you don't know how it's laid out.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quick, this is my first question ever on stackoverflow. I've been trying to get this to work for over 6 hours now, and I can't seem to find the right logic to use, I've tried using jQuery's slice, css selectors gl and lt... It get's really confusing. The jQuery append() was what I started with.

Comment: We need to see a sample of the html (not the php, the html) that you have, and an example of what you want to end up with, showing the dynamically added element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UJdaW/

```
$(function(){
    $(".date").datepicker();
    $("#add").click(function(){
        var id = parseInt( $.datepicker.formatDate('ymmdd', new Date($(".date").val())));
        var el = $("<li>This would be for " + $(".date").val() + "</li>").attr("id",id)
        var lastLi = null;
        $("li").each(function(){
            var currId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
            lastLi = $(this);
            if (currId > id){
                el.insertBefore($(this));
                lastLi=null;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (lastLi){
            el.insertAfter(lastLi);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: that works! it's not working with the pre-existing li's, but its working with the newly added li's.. which is a great start, maybe something i can work with. thank you!

Comment: What do you mean: "it's not working with the pre-existing li's?" What's not working?

Comment: I'm sorry, user error... First, I tried it out and read the dates wrong. It works perfectly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about your question but as far as I concern you want to add a new element between two elements based on their Ids... So have you tried jQuery wrap find it here http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Hope this helps...

Comment: I haven't heard of wrap, but by looking at it seems you would use it to put something inside of a new element. Like if I wanted to put <li>This</li> inside of a <ul> then i would just $("li").wrap("<ul />").. which is not what im looking for. thank you for getting back to me! What im trying to do is get the new id which is based on the date (i.e. 120704, which is the fourth of july, 2012) and place it between two days that already exist, like the 3rd of july (210703) and 5th of september (210805)... the id's are using the event date and formatted using php date("ymd")